# Probability of Random walk with 2 absorbing walls hitting one wall during N steps

Tags: probability

Assume a i.i.d. one dimensional random walk S with symmetrical probabilities of $\frac{1}{2}$ for a unit plus or minus step. Start is at $S = 0$ and absorbing walls are at $S = - B$ and $S = + A$.

What is the probability $P_a$ that during $N$ steps the particle will be absorbed at $S = A$ before reaching $S = - B$ or escaping unabsorbed.  Assume $N > 2A + B$ and assume if necessary $A > B$.

What is the probability $P_u$ that the particle hits neither wall in $N$ steps?

The solution for $N \rightarrow \infty$ or until particle is absorbed is $P_a = \frac{B}{A + B}$. But for finite $N$ this is solved tediously by counting outcomes for specific examples. Can anyone find a closed solution for $P_a$ in terms of $A, B$ and $N$?

This is one of the well-known Gambler's Ruin problems.

Comment: $P_a=(0; 0; ..., 0; 1; 0; ...;0)^TP^N(0;0;...;0;1)$ for $P$ the transition probability matrix, where $x^T$ denotes the transpose of the column vector $x$.

Comment: @Michael Could you please suggest another method? I am not familiar with transition matrix method you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Let $S(t)$ be the Markov chain in the state space $\mathcal{S}=\{-b,...,a\}$.  By the law of total probability $$ \underbrace{P[S(t+1)=j]}_{p_j(t+1)}=\sum_{i\in \mathcal{S}} \underbrace{P[S(t+1)=j|S(t)=i]}_{P_{ij}}\underbrace{P[S(t)=i]}_{p_i(t)}$$ which reduces to $p_j(t+1)=\sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}}p_i(t)P_{ij}$ for all $j\in \mathcal{S}$. Define row vector $p(t)^T = (p_{-b}(t), ..., p_a(t))$.  The matrix version of this is $p(t+1)^T = p(t)^T P$ for all $t \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$. So start with $p(0)^T=(0,...,0,1,0,...,0)$ and iteratively multiply by $P$.